# SESSION variable on jquery-mobile faulty behaviour

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

So I have a list of users and I want to save the selected user in a SESSION variable, I get the index of the cell which contain the user then I use that index to get the position of the array that has the userID and save it to session variable then it jumps to a file named menu.php which should give options for the selected user.

The console.log is showing the SESSION variable OK (the selected user name is on the SESSION variable); but when it goes to menu.php it shows always the name of the last user instead. Am I doing something wrong?

P.S. there is a session_start() in all files.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate",function(event){
    $('.users').click(function(element) {
            var userIdx = $('.users').index(this);
            var userIdxPHP;
            var userID;         
            <?php
                for ($i=0; $i<count($userArray);$i++)
                {
                    ?>
                    userIdxPHP = '<?php echo $i; ?>'    
                    if (userIdx == userIdxPHP)
                    {
                       <?php 
                        $_SESSION['seluserID'] = $userArray[$i]->id; 
                        $_SESSION['seluserName'] = $userArray[$i]->name;
                        ?>  
                        console.log('<?php echo $_SESSION['seluserName']; ?>');
                        document.location.href="menu.php";
                    }
                    <?php
                }
            ?>  
    });
});
```

Comment: sidenote: server side codes are already executed before your jquery code. you should use an xmlhttprequest ajax instead

Comment: just try to refactor your code in such a way that, on pagecreate, you will request from PHP, PHP code processes some data, then just add a response (JSON) in the end of the process that can be used it the client side (the response), not jumbling their code at once.

Comment: Im trying a jquery POST which will jump to menu.php and in the beggining on menu.php I will equal $_POST to $_SESSION. I think that might work.